# java.lang.NullPointerException from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass

Tags: tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception, jax-rs

What causes this? This appears to be a very comon error with myriad causes.

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1149)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1116)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:510)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.3 logs.
```

Here are the includes:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
```

Adding web.xml
Please note: I have tried multiple values for the url-pattern and all it seems to do is change the URI on which I get the error. 'Hello' is the class name in the java source.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldTomcatService</servlet-name>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.package.from.java.file</param-name>
            <param-value>Hello</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldTomcatService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: From the first look it seems to me like an error in servlet or webapp configuration, but it's hard to say without knowing more. Look into `catalina.out` log file and post the full stack trace, and the `web.xml` file of your webapp would be also helpful.

Comment: I think you need to supply: note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.3 logs.

Comment: @RomainHippeau I was unable to find a more detailes stacktrace in any of the log files. Perhaps there's some setting to enable it, but I managed to muddle through without it eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1149)
```

This specific one can be caused by a `web.xml` entry which expects a `<xxx-class>` such as `<servlet-class>`, `<filter-class>` or `<listener-class>`, but it is actually absent or empty.

And indeed, your `<servlet>` entry is missing the `<servlet-class>`. It should refer the FQN of the servlet class you'd like to register under the name as specified by `<servlet-name>` like below.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>someServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.SomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

That said, your `<init-param><param-name>` also doesn't look good if it is actually the JAX-RS servlet you tried to register. Are you sure you're reading the right tutorials/resources as to learning JAX-RS and integrating it in Tomcat? A well known one is provided by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).

Comment: I was actually using that tutorial for a while. Eventually I abandoned it and was able to muddle through doing something like what you said.